# jQuery ajax post not getting return value

Tags: jquery, rest

I have a simple jQuery request that looks like the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/OTM/resteasy/location/coordinates/create',
        data : jsonLatLon,
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(result){
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert(err);
        }
    });
```

In firebug when I look at my console and see the following:
POST: `http://localhost:8080/OTM/resteasy/location/coordinates/create`
then when I expand it I see the data I would expect to see.  However, it's never going to the success call back.

Any ideas on why?

Comment: any error in the browser console? also what is the data returned

Comment: When you look at the javascript console, do you see "Access Denied etc etc etc Same Origin Policy etc etc etc"?

Comment: what is `jsonLatLon` ??

Answer (score -1):

```
in alert you cant see json if you want to see 

then see in console you will see property of objects 

your response come in alert like 

alert(result.property);
```

Answer (score -1):

you have 'jsonLatLon' as your data source. Have you declared that variable with the data you want to be passing across?

Otherwise there would be nothing to return.